# Inequality: $7a+5b+12ab\le9$

Tags: inequality

If we assume that $a,b$ are real numbers such that $9a^2+8ab+7b^2\le 6$, how to prove that :

$$7a+5b+12ab\le9$$

Comment: Think [geometry](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kXvTf.jpg).

Answer (score 10):

We have

$$2(a-b)^2+7\left(a-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + 5\left(b-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \geq 0$$

which is equivalent to

$$7a+5b+12ab\leq 9a^2+7b^2+8ab+3 \leq 6+3=9$$

The motivation here is to search for equality case by solving the system of equation in real values $a,b$

\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
7a+5b+12ab=9 \\
9a^2+7b^2+8ab=6
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

which yields $a=b=\frac{1}{2}$. Thus the factors $\left(a-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$, $\left(b-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$ and $(a-b)^2$ are in order.

Comment: How do you get $a = b = \dfrac{1}{2}$ from the system of equations above?