# Knowing that $9a^2+8ab+7b^2 \le 6$, prove that $7a+5b+12ab \le 9$.

Tags: inequality

Knowing that $9a^2+8ab+7b^2 \le 6$, prove that $7a+5b+12ab \le 9$. I have found the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/196128/inequality-7a5b12ab-le9), but the answer looks wrong. You can't just add two inequalities like him. It's like you would multiply the second one with $-1$, which changes its sign, and then add them.

Here is my try:
$$9a^2 + 9b^2 + 18ab - 2b^2 - 10ab - 6 \le 0 \Longleftrightarrow\\
(3a+3b)^2 - 2(b^2+5ab+3) \le 0 \Longleftrightarrow\\
b^2+5ab+3 \ge 0 \Longleftrightarrow\\
25a^2 - 12 \le 0 \Longleftrightarrow\\
a \in \left[-\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{5}, \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{5} \right]$$

Comment: But this would effectively be a duplicate. If you want a better answer, please put a bounty on the old question instead... Oh wait, unfortunately that question is closed.

Comment: Exactly, it's closed.

Comment: The point in the closed question is that a sum of squares is always non-negative. The answer picks a sum of squares which is relevant to the question and leads to a solution. The answer also tries to explain how that particular sum of squares was discovered.

Comment: @MarkBennet, thanks. I have interpreted it wrong. I thought he subtracted the two inequalities.